# Cannot GET // Error when trying to run javascript on a webserver

Tags: node.js, apache, express

I'm trying to run my js script on my apache2 webserver, but when I visit the scripts page or try to use it, it gives me the error "Cannot GET //". My code is below.

```
const Express = require("express");
const App = Express().use(Express.static(__dirname + '/nodejs'));

const Keys = ["123", "simplewhitelist"]; 
const secretKey2 = "E);{Q6_<bkrEo;ITBzLfLxTdpMuzSzVIs?}5vyus3l@>+?=>O}uL-(A}M/PJ`w";
const Crypto = require("crypto");
function hmac(secret, data){
    const hash = Crypto.createHash("sha512");
    hash.update(secret + data + secret);
    return hash.digest("hex").toString();
};

App.get("xxxx.xyz:8000/nodejs/checkWhitelist", (request, response) => {
    const Key = request.query.Key;
    const Gamer = request.query.gamer;

    if(Key && Gamer){
        const isKeyValid = Keys.find((key) => key !== null && Key == key);

        if(isKeyValid){
            response.send(hmac(secretKey2, Key + Gamer)) valid
        }
        else{
            response.send("Not Whitelisted");
        }
    }
    else{
        response.send("Not Whitelisted");
    }
});

App.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("App started");
});
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to GET? I only see one route here and nothing for `/`.

Comment: Trying to go to webistehere.xyz/nodejs

Comment: Not only that but you need be running some sort of node instance and then within apache you need to setup something like a reverse proxy

Comment: You have not got this set webistehere.xyz/nodejs

Comment: I already have that setup for my apache server.

Comment: No, your route says `/nodejs/checkWhitelist`. `/nodejs` is a 404.

Comment: You have only used `App.get` to define GET for `/nodejs/checkWhitelist`. What do you expect the program to do when you try to GET `/nodejs`?

Comment: you have `webistehere.xyz/nodejs/checkWhitelist` setup

Comment: I get "Cannot GET //checkwhitelist" when I visit that url.

Comment: If you use localhost then you should GET `localhost:8000/nodejs/checkWhitelist`. Also, you forgot to capitalize `W` there

Comment: Still nothing, but i'm not sure if I did it correct, I updated the code above.

Comment: You should run the script using `node [js file]`

Comment: I did that command in my vps (where im hosting it) and still get the error "Cannot GET //checkWhitelist"

Comment: Could you also include the GET request **url** you're trying to access?

Comment: It would be this "xxxx.xyz/nodejs/checkWhitelist". that is what im trying to access.

Comment: Change to `xxxx.xyz:8000/nodejs/checkWhitelist` instead

Comment: updated the code above. still the same

Comment: Not there. In your chrome's url or AJAX requests or wherever you say you get the error from (On the client's side)

Comment: Ok this time the error is "Cannot GET /nodejs/checkWhitelist" when i type ```xxxx.xyz:8000/nodejs/checkWhitelist``` in my browser.

Comment: Did you revert back `App.get("xxxx.xyz:8000/nodejs/checkWhitelist", (request, response) => {` to `App.get("/nodejs/checkWhitelist", (request, response) => {`?

Comment: It works! Thanks soo much!